How to capture only ERROR message (avoid verbose) when connection to sql db in pyspark databricks using JDBC
I need to capture just the reason why I was not able to connect to sql database.
For ex: Login failed for user 'myusername'
I do not need any other verbose descriptions.
Configuring logging:
import logging

# Configure the logger to use a custom format that includes only the error message
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Log a warning, error, debug, and info message
logger.warning("This is a warning message")
logger.error("This is an error message")
logger.debug("About to do something")
logger.info("This is an informational message")

Using JDBC connection to sql database to write dataframe:
try:
    df.write \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://myurl") \
        .option("dbtable", f"dbo.mytable{filename}") \
        .option("user", "myusername") \
        .option("password", "mypwd") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save()
except BaseException as e:
    logger.error('Failed to do something: %s', str(e))

Error:
ERROR:my_logger:Failed to do something: An error occurred while calling o6834.save.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'myusername'. ClientConnectionId:cd6a771a-b3ea-4e91-92aa-70b9317b6e4a
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:300)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6299)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4911)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:90)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4849)


some exceptions may have extra fields - like e.message. But if this exeception doesn't have extra fields then you will have to edit text from str(e) on your own.
